# PHP if "id" null move to url

Tags: php

Need assistance with the following code, i have a form providing a "id", when submitted the next script gets the data from the database, if for some reason the "id" is zero, how can i forward the url to my 404 page.

Code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
        include ('dbconnection.php');
        include ('dbopen.php');
        include ('header.php');
```

I have tried the following, but no success to move client to the 404.php page if "id" value is null.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {

  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Please help :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an error 404 in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit(); // don't execute any code after it!
}
```

Comment: That generates "soft 404" which is going to cause problems for crawlers. When something isn't found you should use `header('HTTP/1.1 404 not found');` and display error without redirecting.

Comment: I know but he asked for this and I think the current protocol is `HTTP/1.0`

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you output HTTP/1.0 or 1.1 — servers will deal with the details for you. Status you output is the key difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. But there shouldn't be any output (echo or content out of ) before header.