# PHP : How to make my own 404 page not found error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create an error 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php)

how to make my own 404 page not found error in my site so it looks better than the default 
when someone accesses url like this www.blablabla.com/index99.php which is doesn't exist this will automatically redirected to my own 404 page
thank beforehand

Comment: Your web server probably just has a template page you can replace, if it is only to be static output.

Comment: What web server software are you using? It's fairly easy in most of them. Just search for "custom 404 [web server software]".

Comment: It has nothing to do with php. You have either forward all requests with mod_rewrite (if you are using Apache) to the script which will check the existence of the requested page or setup http server. This is an example for Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html

Comment: thank you for all of you, yes i'm using Apache web Server

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. Make your own custom 404 page
2. [Make an .htaccess file](https://example.com/) and place it in your root
3. Place this line inside the .htaccess file `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/your-custom-404.php`

Read more [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/custom404error.html)

Comment: It's quite ironic and funny that the link you shared in step 2 gives a 404 error page =) but it doesn't matter, most of us won't need a guide on how to create a file...

Comment: the irony...linking me to an 404 error page.. :P