# .htaccess handling all URI in database but return 404 otherwise

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm developing a highly dynamic website that needs to handle a lot of URI that do not actually have a file behind them. So I used .htaccess to redirect all non-existing URI to a php file that displays what I need based on the URI by looking into various tables in a database and including the correct web-pages.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /urihandling.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will produce a 200 OK Status and keeps the URI in the address-bar so it's exactly what I want.

Now my problem is, if the user accesses a URL that is not in the database, I want to redirect to a custom 404 page (e.g. 404.html) and produce the status code 404 Not found.

First I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /urihandling.php [L,NC,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

That does **not** load 404.html when I use

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

in my urihandling.php file. In fact, it doesn't load anything, it just shows a blank page (if I erase the Rewrite commands, the 404 works fine, so the syntax etc. seems to be ok).
I thought maybe the problem is that the 404 triggers the rewrite and then it's going into some sort of redirect-loop or something.

Then I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /404.* /404.html [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /urihandling.php [L,NC,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /403.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

With or without the ErrorDocument makes no difference. Then in my urihandling.php I used

```
header('Location: http://somesite.com/404.html');
```

This works as far as the user is concerned, but looking at the status codes in the HTTP headers, I get a HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

So my question is, how can I achive this and still get a 404 status code?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
[How can I create an error 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php)

Which means this is more likely then not, a duplicate.
But alas, as an answer:

```
 header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
 include("http://somesite.com/404.html");
```

should be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work. But it does. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As your script handling request, it should generate 404 header itself, so it'll be like that:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

and output your 404.html after that without redirection

Comment: I thought I tried that, but I guess not. Thank you!