# How do I create customized 404 error page for a website?

Tags: php, html, css

While creating 404 error page the page contents of other pages can be modified and it is created . But how to do it?

After creating 404 error pages , explain how to redirect it.

How to rectify the broken links?

Comment: see [How can I create an error 404 in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php)

Comment: In general: The same way as any other page… and then you tell your (unspecified so we can't go into specifics) HTTP server that the file should be used for 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Custom Error Page with Apache 2.2+ and PHP**

.htaccess or vhost settings:

```
# in .htaccess you need AllowOverride in the /error directory
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

**Custom Error Page with Nginx and PHP**

add the part below in your nginx server config like: (/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf)

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location  /404.php {
  internal;
}
```

**Custom Error Page with lighttpd and PHP**

add the script below in your lighttpd config:

```
server.errorfile-prefix = "/srv/www/htdocs/errors/status-"
```

and make error pages with the syntax like:

```
/srv/www/htdocs/errors/status-404.php
/srv/www/htdocs/errors/status-500.php
```

*404.php*

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
echo 'The Page'. $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. ' cannot be found!';
```

**More Infos about this**

- [Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html)
- [Nginx Tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-nginx-customizing-404-403-error-page/)
- [lighttpd Manual](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_errorfile-prefixDetails)
- [PHP Manual: header](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)
- [PHP Manual: $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: **Check this Working Concept**

[Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php/36306284#36306284)