# Get the site root host name dynamically in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make 404, 500 etc pages in ErrorDocument in php .htaccess file, it works fine if give

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/project/errordocs/404.html
```

but  i do not want to hard code the url here, instead i want to get the root url site name dynamically so that i do not have change it again and again as the hostname changes.

Basically i want to get this root url like: `http://localhost/project` can change to `http://www.example1.com/project` or `http://www.example2.com/project` etc. This url must come from projects root folder.

So that will dynamically become:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/project/errordocs/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example1.com/project/errordocs/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example2.com/project/errordocs/404.html
```

Any help please?

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.html

Comment: it will not work as it will refer as `http://localhost/errordocs/404.html` but i want reference as `http://localhost/project/errordocs/404.html`

Comment: Save project. I thought your root is  there ErrorDocument 404 /project/errordocs/404.html

Comment: You should  say  the path from document_root

Comment: the problem is that i do not want to hard code `/project/`, i want to get it dynamically

Comment: If this is root of web site, my 1st comment must work. If project dir into the web, i must think. Where your htacces is placed?

Comment: yes i know that, but i do not want to that as most of the time the projects in localhost are not in root document but it is contained in separate project folders. I want to do something like, `ErrorDocument 404 %{HTTP_HOST}/errordocs/404.html`

Comment: This is my 1st comment - if htaccess at document root :))) `ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.html ` -  Apache make DOCUMENT_ROOT./errordocs/404.html

Comment: yes the htaccess is at the project root folder in my localhost

Comment: `http://localhost/errordocs/404.html` says that document root at localhost but not at localhst/project

Comment: yup, but i want to do as `http://localhost/project/errordocs/404.html` that is my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79890/discussion-between-splash58-and-sourabh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asker asks incorrect. All what he writes

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/project/errordocs/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example1.com/project/errordocs/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example2.com/project/errordocs/404.html
```

may be done by

```
ErrorDocument 404 /project/errordocs/404.html
```

But really he want: while moving site from project folder to project1, he should not change the rule

I think it may be done by htacces placed in /project with code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^  errordocs/404.html [L]
```

It will work if AllowOverride set to All (it is default).

The problem only that responce in this case will be 200 but not 404

Comment: I think you can use the flag `[R=404,L]` to set the status 404, according to the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel in this case (R=404) Apache will return standard error doc. Or user error doc setting by ErrorDocument. But the last does not take a relative path

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You may try to set `ErrorDocument 404 smdir/smdoc.html` (without leading slash) it produces string `smdir/smdoc.html` in browser

Comment: According to the doc, it will make an external request and will return the error 404. But that was just an attempt to get a nice 404. Maybe a `<meta>` tag in the document will do that? I never tried it. Using php instead of html, and the function `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].' 404 Not Found');` will do the trick (Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381123/how-can-i-create-an-error-404-in-php).

Comment: I never used too. Using php may get the correct result.

Comment: @Sourabh I glad that our discussion gave the result :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [conversation you had](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79890/discussion-between-splash58-and-sourabh), you would like to not have to change the path to the error document when you move your project to another folder with a different name.

Firstly, you cannot use variables when using `ErrorDocument`. The path that you provide must be static. The path that you specify must be either to an external URL (in which case your browser will be redirected) or to a file relative to your document root (i.e. `localhost`).

Unfortunately, `ErrorDocument` won't be able to find the file relative to the current directory (i.e. `project`). The only logical way of doing this would be to remove the leading slash, but this would cause Apache to render that as a string in the browser.

This brings us to the only other possible solution: `mod_rewrite`. The only problem with using it, however, is that it is **processed early on in the mapping pipeline** which **may allow other modules (such as mod_proxy) to affect the process**.

That said, you can try with the following:

**`/project/.htaccess`:**

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# Determine if the request does not match an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If so, send the request to the applicable file, relative to this directory
RewriteRule ^ errordocs/404.php [L]

# Per your comment and suggested edit, add the following.
# Note: This should not make any difference as mod_rewrite and PHP should
# already handle the error document.
ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.php
```

**`/project/errordocs/404.php`:**

This file will send the 404 header as `.htaccess` won't be able to do that.

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>

<h1>Sorry, we couldn't find that...</h1>
<p>The thing you've requested doesn't exist here. Perhaps it flew away?</p>
```

Comment: @Sourabh - why did you make that edit? That would cause it to not work because the path must be specified from the document root (i.e. `localhost`). Please read carefully before making edits. I have tested this on my server, and it does indeed work as intended.

Comment: you haven't specified the error document in the code which was my real problem

Comment: Indeed it should, but there is effectively no difference. It worked without it on my side. Will update my answer to reflect your edit anyway.

Comment: Thanks, 1 up vote from me :), it works without even the error document. Thanks again